# Using mongoDB aggregation function $min querying

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using the dataset [media.mongodb.org/zips.json](http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json) where each document in the collection looks like

> {   "_id": "10280",   "city": "NEW YORK",   "state": "NY",   "pop":
>   5574,   "loc": [
>       -74.016323,
>       40.710537   ] }

Please suggest on how I can write a query to find the city with least population by state?

I found the following query to Return Average City Population by State which works  fine

```
db.collection1.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: { state: "$state", city: "$city" }, pop: { $sum: "$pop" } } },
   { $group: { _id: "$_id.state", avgCityPop: { $avg: "$pop" } } }
] )
```

Because I am new to mongodb queries, I tried editing the same query to find the minimum too but getting an error

```
 db.collection1.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: { state: "$state", city: "$city" }, pop: { $sum: "$pop" } } },
   { $group: { _id: "$_id.city”, minCityPop: { $min: "$pop" } } }
] )
```

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Please suggest what is wrong in this query or a different query??

Thank you

Comment: As the syntax highlighting shows, you seem to have a stray smart quote instead of a normal double quote at the end of `"$_id.city`. Might just be that.

Comment: You were right @JohnnyHK, Thanks :)

Comment: The query works but I am not getting the result, right now I am getting  this { "_id" : null, "avgCityPop" : 0 }. Whereas,  I am looking for something like this { "_id" : NEW YORK, "avgCityPop" : 5574 } - Assuming this is the city with the minimum population in the whole document.

Comment: @nshetty This task looks familiar to me. M102 or M202? If that is the case, you should read the [open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) thoroughly. Not only are you lessening the worth of said class for you (and others). You are short cutting a simple task. And you are going to need *personal* experience for the DBA/CD exam, as googling and SOing is not possible.